# Best way to model my mixed monthly/yearly subscription with Stripe payments

Tags: stripe-payments

## The subscription plan

I have a subscription plan available at my app which I need to model with Stripe.

The subscription plan details are the following:

- A fixed amount of $20/month or $200/year (discounted) that the user must pay.
- With the previous fixed amount the user can consume 2500 units of the product per month.
- If the user consume more than 2500 units in one month every additional unit has a value of $0,01.

### Examples

1. A user choose the subscription plan with the $20/month option and in the first month he/she consumes 2520 units.

The total amount to pay for the first month of the subscription for this user is:

- $20 fixed amount
- 20 additional units * $0,01 = $0,2
- Total to pay: $20 + $0,2 = $20,2

2. A user choose the subscription plan with the $200/year option. In the first month he/she consumes 500 units. In the second month he/she consumes 5000 units.

For the first month this user needs to pay:

- $200 because is starting the subscription
- No additional units.
- Total to pay: $200

For the second month this user needs to pay:

- No fixed amount because the fixed yearly quantity has already been paid.
- 2500 additional units * $0,01 = $25
- Total to pay: $25

### Problems

My biggest problem modeling this with Stripe payments is that is not possible to have prices with different intervals in the same subscription.

If the user chooses the yearly fixed price is not possible to create a subscription on Stripe that has a fixed yearly pay (of $200 in this case) and a monthly graduated price (for the additional consumed units).

I have seen that the [subscription upsell](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/upsells) feature is something very similar to what a I need. But once it's activated I can't find any way on the API to enable it when the subscription is created (I'm not using checkout).

I have seen also that it's possible to create two subscriptions, one for the yearly pay and another one for the monthly units. But creating two subscriptions make everything really difficult, you need to take into account two subscription states and callbacks are more difficult this way too.

### Questions

What is the best and simple way to model this subscription plan using Stripe?

> Note: I'm doing a custom integration with Stripe, so the subscriptions and customer are created via API. I'm not using Stripe checkout.

Comment: I was wondering if you found a way to solve for your original question here - I have the same pricing model idea. Did you find a way to solve for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My biggest problem modeling this with Stripe payments is that is not possible to have prices with different intervals in the same subscription.

Indeed, you can't combine Price objects with different intervals on a single Subscription. Otherwise, this pricing is possible by combining a flat rate fee with metered usage as outlined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#flat-rate-metered-usage).

Your best option in cases where your customers elect for the annual fixed fee is to roll with a single usage based Price and amend the initial invoice to include that a one-off Invoice Item for the annual fixed fee.

> I have seen that the subscription upsell feature is something very similar to what a I need. But once it's activated I can't find any way on the API to enable it when the subscription is created (I'm not using checkout).

Subscription upsells are a Checkout only feature right now. However this is not really related to the problem you're facing (it just provides a UI for your customers to upgrade to an annual Price for the same Product).

Comment: Sorry Jonathan I'm not sure about the "one-off invoice item for the annual fixed fee" solution. Does this means that I need someway to modify the invoice to add the yearly payment? So this is not managed by Stripe and my app needs to do it in a yearly basis?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add a [one-time Invoice Item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create) to the generated Invoice at each annual billing cycle. There's no way to combine a fixed yearly fee with a monthly usage based fee as you need automatically, so there will be manual work required in your integration.